# BigQuery Temp Table Column has no Name

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm trying to create a temp table in BigQuery, something like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE myTmpTable AS
  SELECT t.event_id, MAX(t.event_date)
  FROM eventsTable t
  WHERE t.field_name = "foo"
  AND t.new_string = "bar"
  GROUP BY t.event_id;
```

This results in error "CREATE TABLE columns must be named, but column 2 has no name". I understand that it can't extract a column name from MAX(t.event_date). Is there a way I can specify a column name?

Comment: Is there a way I can specify a column name? - `SELECT t.event_id, MAX(t.event_date) AS max_event_date`. Meantime the whole SELECT looks wrong to me - if you group by `issue_id` then `event_id` should be somehow aggregated. Or you might want to group by `event_id` instead!

Comment: oh thanks @MikhailBerlyant - that works, I was trying something like MAX(t.event_date) "max_event_date". D'oh. If you want to post as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can specify a column name?

Use below

```
SELECT t.event_id, MAX(t.event_date) AS max_event_date
```

Meantime the whole SELECT looks wrong to me - if you group by issue_id then event_id should be somehow aggregated. Or you might want to group by event_id instead!

Comment: Thanks, yeah that was a typo, I've corrected it now to "GROUP BY t.event_id;"